# Google Spreadsheet - Как заменить данные в ячейке

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Я через один сервис - записываю данные в таблицу в виде например:

- Date Name            Email           Status
- 2016    Eugen        test@test.com   NEW

Потом, через API вытягиваю таблицу в виде JSON
и проверяю циклом, если статус NEW, то отправить сообщение на почту.

На данный момент нужно, после отправки письма менять статус с NEW например на PENDING

Подскажите как это можно сделать через макрос Google App Script
Заранее Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение найдено.

```
function doGet(event) {
  var email = event.parameter.email;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREATSHEET ID"); //SPREADSHEET ID заменить на Ваш id таблицы
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var grid = dataRange.getValues();

  grid.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (row[2] == email) {
      var row = "D" + (index + 1);
      sheet.getRange(row).setValue('inPROGRESS');
    }
  });
}
```

API ожидает получить переменную "email"